# mount: fmask options is not working

Tags: permissions, mount, vfat

Few days ago I did this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124160/mounting-a-device-without-read-permissions). But now I have another problem, related, but new.

Scenario:

I have a flash drive (vfat) mounted in `/media/flash` the filesystem node is `/dev/sdb1`.

according to linux manuals [mount(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) under the section **Mount options for fat**:

> *fmask: Set the umask applied to regular files only. The default is the umask of the current process. The value is given in octal.*

So since I'm trying nobody be able to read anything from this flash drive I did:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/flash -o remount,fmask=444
```

but I'm still able to read the content of a *.txt file stored in the mentioned device. What I'm doing wrong?